# What is $\operatorname{ord}_{22}(5^6)$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, multiplicative-order

> Find $\operatorname{ord}_{22}(5^6)$.

So, basically we want to find:$$\operatorname*{arg\,min}_k 5^{6k} \equiv 1\pmod {22}$$

I found that $5^5 \equiv 1\pmod {22}$ so I know that for $k=5$ we have $5^{6k} \equiv 1 \pmod {22}$. Therefore, $\text{ord}(5^6) \le 5$.

I guess that I could proceed with the somewhat tedious checking:

1. $k=4$: $(5^6)^4 \equiv (5^4)^6 \equiv 5^4 \equiv 9 \pmod {22}$
2. $k=3$  $(5^6)^3 \equiv (5^3)^6 \equiv 5^3 \equiv 15 \pmod {22}$
3. $k=2$  $(5^6)^2 \equiv (5^2)^6 \equiv 5^2 \equiv 3 \pmod {22}$
4. $k=1$  $(5^6)^1 \equiv (5^1)^6 \equiv 5 \pmod {22}$

So $\text{ord}_{22}(5^6) = 5$.

**Questions:**

1. Is that what I'm expected to do? Or is there a simpler way? (I had to use a calculator or to tediously calculate it myself)
2. Why can we get rid of the exponent when we do modular arithmetic? (I actually used it along the proof) i.e. $$x \equiv a \pmod m \iff x^b \equiv a \pmod m$$

Comment: It should be `\operatorname{ord}` rather than `\text{ord}` and `\operatorname*{arg\,min}_k` rather than `\arg\min_k`

Comment: okay, I'll edit accordingly

Comment: When you found $5^5\equiv 1\pmod{22}$ you could have noted that $5^6\equiv5\pmod{22}$ so  that $\text{ord}_{22}(5^6)=\text{ord}_{22}(5)$. Then since $5^5\equiv1\pmod{22}$, the order is either $1$ or $5$, and it's not $5$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have found that $5^5 \equiv 1 \pmod {22}$. So as $5^6 \equiv 5 \pmod {22}$. Then we must have $\text{ord}(5^6) = \text{ord}(5)$. But from the first equation we have that $\text{ord}(5) \mid 5$ and as $5$ is prime and $5^1 \not \equiv 1 \pmod {22}$ we must have that $\text{ord}(5^6) = \text{ord}(5) = 5$

---

Note that we used the fact that if $a^{k} \equiv 1\pmod {p}$, then $\text{ord}_p(a) \mid k$. This can be easily proven by the Division Algorithm. Let $k = \text{ord}_p(a)\cdot m + r$, where $0 \le r < \text{ord}_p(a)$. Then:

$$1 \equiv a^k \equiv (a^{\text{ord}_p(a)})^m \cdot a^r \equiv a^r \pmod {p} $$

So $r=0$, as $\text{ord}_p(a)$ is the smallest positive integer $t$ s.t. $a^t \equiv 1 \pmod {p}$ by definition

Comment: Thank you and thanks all for helping!

Answer (score 1):

First observe that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
5^6 \equiv 5 \pmod{22}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So we only need to calculate powers of $5$ modulo $22$, they are $5,3,15,9,1$ (by tedious calculation), the minimal value of $k$ is $\color{red}{5}$.

Answer (score 0):

By the Chinese remainder theorem, it is enough to find the order of $5^6$ $\!\!\pmod{2}$ (which is obviously $1$) and the order of $5^6\equiv5$ $\!\!\pmod{11}$. Since $5$ is a quadratic residue $\!\!\pmod{11}$, due to
$$\left(\frac{5}{11}\right)=\left(\frac{11}{5}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)=1$$
the order of $5\pmod{11}$ is five and that is also the order of $5^6\pmod{22}$.